# Query a Google Sheet using POST method

Tags: post, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I use the UrlFetchApp to execute the query of Sheet in Google App Script.  It works fine if my query string is not too long.  As the url size limit of UrlFetchApp is only 2k.  I would like to know if it is possible to use POST method to execute the query?

I tried below.  But it does not work.

```
url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SHEETKEY/gviz/tq'
var payload = {
  gid = sheetid,
  tq = myquerystring,
};
var options = {
 method:'POST',
 payload:payload
};
UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

Comment: You are using a `/gviz/tq` URL to execute a Google Visualization Query.  Is that correct?  [Link to Documentation - Using OAuth to access /gviz/tq](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets#example-using-oauth-to-access-gviztq)

Comment: Yes, I am.  I would like to know if I could use POST method instead of GET as the size limit of POST is 10MB.